# What's _M prefix mean in libstdc++?

Tags: libstdc++

Recently, I went through the library code of lib c++. As there are lot's internal functions with prefix _M, like:

```
      void
  _M_add_ref_copy()
  { __gnu_cxx::__atomic_add_dispatch(&_M_use_count, 1); }
```

Interesting on what's meaning of prefix: _M

Comment: Identifiers starting with `_` and an upper-case letter are reserved to the implementation, so that part of it makes sense, especially if they didn't want to use names like `_Add_ref_copy`.  Now why `_M` and not, say, `_X`, I don't know.

Comment: The libstdc coding conventions are [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/source_code_style.html](documented here). In particular, it says "Member data and function names: `_M_.*`."

Comment: @ Raymond, Thank you.